# Countifs and Partial Matching

Tags: excel, match, countif

Here is my code that is partially working`{=IF(CG!D:D="*"&Homeports!B16:B42&"*"<>0,COUNTIFS(CG!C:C,"*MARMC*",CG!H:H,"*TECH*"),0)}`

My result should be to count the cells that contain *MARMC* and *TECH*, but only count them if columns CG!D:D and Homeports!B16:B42 match.... only partially. 
    `Example: a cell in column CG!D:D has the word **USS New York (LPD)** while a cell in column Homeports!B16:B42 has the word **USS New York**`

Without adding numerous `COUNTIFS(CG!C:C,"<>*whatever*)` to exclude the cells with words that I don't want to count.

Comment: I think that the best way for you is to add a column with all yor conditions (using AND, OR, NOT, FIND, ...) and, in that column write TRUE or FALSE if you have to count that value. Than apply the COUNTIF. Once you have finished you can put all togheter into a big formula.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.